# Cant get QuickBlox Sample Modules to work in iOS

Tags: ios, quickblox

I managed to get the SimpleSample Message to work in `Android`, but cant get it to work in iOS. I am using the injoituser1 and created a provisioning profile incl. `APNs`. I dont get error messages in the Console, but when I activate the app only the `QuickBlox SplashViewController.xib with a spinning loading wheel appears. Same happens with`ModuleLocator`. It asks for permission to use my location and then only the SplashViewController.xib appears. Had someone the same issues? What could be wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose what kind of push notification you will generate: android or ios. To send push notification, go to Admin Panel / your App / Messages and choose APNS or GCM. It sends push notification to all ios or all android users, not both. Also you can add tag for group of users you want to send push notifications. 
The SimpleSample Message also shows how to send push notifications from user to user.

For correct work of push notifications on QuickBlox:

1. It doesn't work on simulator.
2. You must create application in Admin Panel and put your APNS or GCM certificate in: "yourApp/Messages/Settings/".
3. Put your app credentials from Admin Panel to AppDelegate.
4. You should have provisioning profile/certificate with enabled Push notifications.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but as I said. I got it to work on Android. So I did all that and I dont get an error message in Xcode anymore. It just doent work.

Comment: Did you send P.N. from Admin Panel or from another ios device?

Comment: From Admin Panel. I believe my problem must be the registration of my device with QBlox.